# In Shroud of the Avatar, what is the golden shield on the right of your screen?

Tags: shroud-of-the-avatar

What is the golden shield with the blue circle on the right of your screen?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means some piece of armor has suffered durability loss that will lower its effectiveness.  It will eventually turn red if that piece of armor is broken.